# jquery reset after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset, jquery-after

is there a way to reset/update an `after()` element? Not add another `after()` text. Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will helpful.

(Controller function for Emptiness of Form to be sent Server Input parameter ID of Form Parent DIV, output is 1-true, 0 false)

```
 function emptynessCntrl(elementosForControl){
      var controlResult=1;
        $(elementosForControl).find('input').each(function() {
            if($(this).val().trim()===""){
              controlResult=0;
              console.log($(this).attr('id')+' Element is empty');
              $(this).nextAll().remove();
              $(this).after('<div class="err-label">'+$(this).attr('placeholder')+' is empty</div>');
              return controlResult;
              } 
              else{
                $(this).nextAll().remove();
              }        
           });
        return controlResult;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I'll asume you want to modify an element added with `.after()`

Instead of doing this:

```
$("#elem1").after('<div id="after />");
```

You could do this (use `insertAfter`)

```
$('<div id="after" />').insertAfter("#elem1").attr("width", 200).html("hi") ...;
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the element, give it a name

```
var newElement = $('<span>Some new stuff</span>');
$('.whatever').after(newElement);
```

Then, when you want to change it, simply remove the previous one first

```
newElement.remove();
newElement = $('<div>And now for something completely different</div>');
$('.whatever').after(newElement);
```

---

You can write a function that uses `.data()` to remember the new element as such: (I would change the names a bit though)

```
$.fn.addUniqueSomething = function (content) {
    var existing = this.data('something-that-was-already-added');
    if (existing) {
        existing.remove();
    }

    var something = $(content);
    this.after(something);
    this.data('something-that-was-already-added', something);
};
```

Then you can use

```
$('.whatever').addUniqueSomething('<span>Some new stuff</span>');
// and later...
$('.whatever').addUniqueSomething('<div>And now for something completely different</div>');
```

And the second one will replace the first