# Clear after(data) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
$("#results").after(data)
```

Here "results" is a DIV. I have added this code to get some database results and display them after this div as soon as i click a button. Problem is when i click the button again it will show another result after previous result set. I want to find a way to remove  clear/remove or reset the previous results.
If it is inside DIV i can use .empty() without any problem. But it dosen't remove data added by .after()

I found old link regarding this, but there is no answer in it.
[jquery reset after()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917624/jquery-reset-after)

Comment: did you try $( "#results" ).empty(); ? ? ? 

jus add $( "#results" ).empty(); before adding data to the div , so every time when button click , first it clear the div & then add the data to it

Comment: Its relate with a Database. I don't know how to get database results using jsfiddle. sorry

Comment: You can always mock them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a results div after `#results` and then set the content on that:

```
if ($('#resultsdiv').length === 0) {
    $('#results').after('<div id="resultsdiv" />');
}

$('#resultsdiv').html(data);
```

This will replace the old results with the new each time it is called.

Comment: I already have data in that DIV. I must add .after() part here. cant mess with the data inside the div. thanx

Comment: this if condition will always be TRUE. because i always have data with the query. Somehow i want to clear previous data .after("CLEAR THESE DATA") . thanks anyways

Comment: @TharakaandRukshan This will clear the data. The first time this code is hit it will create an additional div after the existing results div and put the data into that. Then on the next call it will just replace the data in the new div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following, add a div after results like below :

```
<id="results"></div>
<id="afterResult"></div>
```

And use below jquery :

```
$("#afterResult").html(data)
```